# MUI Grid: items do not change their width despite defining the columns for items

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid

So i was following a tutorial, where the items would change depending on the size of the screen. And would take up the whole width if defined the following way:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
   <div>
     <Grid container>
       <Grid>
         <Paper item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>1</Paper>
       </Grid>
       <Grid>
         <Paper item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>2</Paper>
       </Grid>
       <Grid>
         <Paper item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>3</Paper>
       </Grid>
       <Grid>
         <Paper item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>4</Paper>
       </Grid>
     </Grid>
   </div>
  );
}}
```

Well for me, no matter the width of my screen it always looks like this:
[image]

I see no reason for it not to work, but somehow the elements don't stretch to take up the complete width of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you are doing here is that you are adding the `Grid` properties (`item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}`) in the `Paper` component instead of the `Grid` item.

Here is the right code:

```
return (
    <div>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
          <Paper>1</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
          <Paper>2</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
          <Paper>3</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
          <Paper>4</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
```

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-vaughan-o394kx?file=/demo.tsx) with your example

Comment: Oh that was actually it! Thanks